# How could go module auto pull the latest version of dependency instead of assign a specific tag

Tags: go, go-modules

In general I tag the dependency and require it in go.mod file, for example:

```
require (
    private-gitlab.com/domain/common v1.0
)
```

Whenever I update **private-gitlab.com/domain/common**, I assign a new tag to it such as **v1.1**, then change the requirement

```
require (
    private-gitlab.com/domain/common v1.1
)
```

Once apply microservices architecture, there are multiple microservices require this dependency, so that I should change their tags from **v1.0** to **v1.1**

Does go module support latest/snapshot tag (something like java maven snapshot) so that it would auto detect and pull the latest version of dependency, like

```
require (
    private-gitlab.com/domain/common qa@latest
)
```

Comment: If your really want to always use the latest then you probably should not put it into its own module. Maybe just one module is good enough. Modules in Go tend to be larger than what you might be accostomed.

Answer (score 4):

Go's module system ought to provide reproducible builds. So without the user's consent, the `go` tool cannot just fetch a newer version arbitrarily from one build to another if a newer version is available.

The user has to update the dependencies explicitly, e.g. by running:

```
go get example.com/theirmodule@latest
```

If you want to see if there are any dependencies that have updates (newer versions), you may run:

```
go list -m -u all
```

If you want to update all direct and indirect dependencies of your module (excluding test dependencies), you may run:

```
go get -u ./...
```

To update all direct and indirect dependencies including test dependencies, you may run:

```
go get -u -t ./...
```